# How can I make an application be recognised as a camera app by windows applications?

Tags: windows, filter, webcam

I want to make an app that can add color filters to the camera stream, and be able to use this app as my camera in Zoom or Discord for example, so I would need it to appear as an option for a camera in the settings of these applications.

I have tried to search for an answer, but I just can't seem to find a way to phrase my search such that I get relevant answers.

I have not yet started this project, any advice or relevant sources would be appreciated.